# Delivering Business Intelligence with SQL Server Analysis Services over the web

Tags: sql-server, olap, business-intelligence, ssas

I have a cube developed using SQL Server Analysis Services (2005). Its hooked up to an excel front end.

At the moment users have their own logon to the reporting server and access the reports that way. However, it would be nice of they could access the reports over the web.

Are there options for this? I could upgrade to 2008 if there was a compelling case.

Answer (score 0):

The reporting server runs on IIS, so you'd need to treat this as any other IIS server.  Common practice is to not expose a database server directly to the internet, so you would want to have a separate server hosting reporting services, which needs another SQL license - if you are not already configured that way.

I'm not sure if you're asking for a way to connect a local excel to the cube, or if you're just wanting to get into the reports interface.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using the aspxpivotgrid to expose your cube data within a web app. http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Pivot_Grid/

note:  not an employee of developerexpress

Answer (score 0):

CellSetGrid is an Open Source ASP .Net (c#) control, which offers pivot table like functionality.

[This used to be available for download in this site:

www.SQLServerAnalysisServices.com

Now the site does not host this control anymore. So I have uploaded the source of the control - **CellSetGrid** here.

http://www.box.net/shared/6gi0n79q6t

1) You can build the source
2) Add this as a Control in Visual Studio toolbox.
3) Drag and Drop control to a web form
4) Set the connection string to the cube
5) This will show all the dimensions and measure groups so you can drag n drop what you want to get a pivot table like functionality

Answer (score 0):

SSRS is running on IIS, meaning user can access the reports over web with proper access permission.

Also you can build a custom ASP.NET application with ReportViewer control which is using almost the same report file used in report server.